# How can I convert a String to a char array?

Tags: java, string, arrays

Is there any function to do this kind of job or do one have to parse each char and add it to the array?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`String#toCharArray()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29).

```
char[] chars = "some string".toCharArray();
```

Comment: Damn! 14 seconds! +1 because I don't want to be a sore loser :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
"read java docs".toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`String.toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`String.getChars()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getChars%28int,%20int,%20char%5B%5D,%20int%29) method.