# How to convert/parse from String to char in java?

Tags: java, string, parsing, char

How do I parse a `String` value to a `char` type, in Java?

I know how to do it to int and double (for example `Integer.parseInt("123")`).
Is there a class for Strings and Chars?

Comment: You want to parse a String into a char array? Please be more specific.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert a String to a char array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804550/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-a-char-array)

Comment: Yeah but I don't see any method in it that will help me change a String such as "a" to a char such as 'a'

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate. I am trying to just convert a single letter.

Answer (score 337, accepted):

If your string contains exactly one character the simplest way to convert it to a character is probably to call the [`charAt`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) method:

```
char c = s.charAt(0);
```

Comment: For more than one character:  char[] c = s.toCharArray();

Answer (score 76):

You can use the [.charAt(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) function with Strings to retrieve the char value at any index. If you want to convert the String to a char array, try calling [.toCharArray()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) on the String.

```
String g = "line";
char c = g.charAt(0);  // returns 'l'
char[] c_arr = g.toCharArray(); // returns a length 4 char array ['l','i','n','e']
```

Comment: Well, true, although I was seeking to convert a single character in a string, I guess that could work too.

Answer (score 48):

you can use this trick :

```
String s = "p";

char c = s.charAt(0);
```

Comment: But that will turn `"123"` into `'1'`, is that what you're after?

Comment: I didn't mean to specifically use "123". I was just using as an example. For char it would be a different example like "p" since a char is a single character, not multiple ones.

Comment: the toCharArray() function returns an array of chars in case you want to split your string into chars

Answer (score 14):

I found this useful:

```
double  --> Double.parseDouble(String);
float   --> Float.parseFloat(String);
long    --> Long.parseLong(String);
int     --> Integer.parseInt(String);
char    --> stringGoesHere.charAt(int position);
short   --> Short.parseShort(String);
byte    --> Byte.parseByte(String);
boolean --> Boolean.parseBoolean(String);
```

Comment: Why thumbs down? This really answer the question, so as you can check how to parse in other types

Comment: @Davide Probably because posts should't include the important information as image when it can be posted as text. Images can't be searched and copy/pasted, are often blocked and can't be read by users relying on screen readers.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Comment: I agree with @Davide question - "Why thumbs down?". I believe that this will make the user that got this not to contribute with stackoverflow in the future and I believe that this should not be the case. From my perspective "thumbs down" should not ever be used! It's negative in its essence and doesn't bring any value at all.

Comment: Are you sure that `char    --> StringGoesHere.parseFloat(int position);` is correct?  Honestly I haven't checked, but I'm fairly sure `String` doesn't have a `parseFloat` method, and even if it does, I can't see why that would be what you'd be trying to do there.

Answer (score 9):

If the string is 1 character long, just [take that character](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29). If the string is not 1 character long, it cannot be parsed into a character.

Comment: Maybe a hack, but can be done. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21813888/build-char-from-string

Comment: Your statement saying that a string longer than 1 character can't be parsed to an integer is wrong, see my answer.

Comment: @Adam: Your answer is wrong, I'll explain in a comment.

Answer (score 5):

```
 String string = "This is Yasir Shabbir ";
 for(char ch : string.toCharArray()){

 }
```

or If you want individually then you can as

```
char ch = string.charAt(1);
```

Answer (score 4):

[org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava%28java.lang.String).(un)EscapeJava methods are probaby what you want

Answer from brainzzy not mine :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8736043/1130448

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to convert a `String` to a `char` is using `charAt()`:

```
String stringAns="hello";
char charAns=stringAns.charAt(0);//Gives You 'h'
char charAns=stringAns.charAt(1);//Gives You 'e'
char charAns=stringAns.charAt(2);//Gives You 'l'
char charAns=stringAns.charAt(3);//Gives You 'l'
char charAns=stringAns.charAt(4);//Gives You 'o'
char charAns=stringAns.charAt(5);//Gives You:: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
```

Here is a full script:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class demo {
    String accNo,name,fatherName,motherName;
    int age;
    static double rate=0.25;
    static double balance=1000;
    Scanner scanString=new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scanNum=new Scanner(System.in);

    void input()
    {
        System.out.print("Account Number:");
        accNo=scanString.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Name:");
        name=scanString.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Father's Name:");
        fatherName=scanString.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Mother's Name:");
        motherName=scanString.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Age:");
        age=scanNum.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
    }

    void withdraw() {
        System.out.print("How Much:");
        double withdraw=scanNum.nextDouble();
        balance=balance-withdraw;
        if(balance<1000)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Data Entry\n Balance below Rs 1000 not allowed");
            System.exit(0);
        }       
    }

    void deposit() {
        System.out.print("How Much:");
        double deposit=scanNum.nextDouble();
        balance=balance+deposit;
    }

    void display() {
        System.out.println("Your  Balnce:Rs "+balance);
    }

    void oneYear() {
        System.out.println("After one year:");
        balance+=balance*rate*0.01;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        demo d1=new demo();
        d1.input();
        d1.display();
        while(true) {//Withdraw/Deposit
            System.out.println("Withdraw/Deposit Press W/D:");
            String reply1= ((d1.scanString.nextLine()).toLowerCase()).trim();
            char reply=reply1.charAt(0);
            if(reply=='w') {
                d1.withdraw();
            }
            else if(reply=='d') {
                d1.deposit();
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
            }
            //More Manipulation 
            System.out.println("Want More Manipulations: Y/N:");
            String manipulation1= ((d1.scanString.nextLine()).toLowerCase()).trim();

            char manipulation=manipulation1.charAt(0);
            System.out.println(manipulation);

            if(manipulation=='y') { }
            else if(manipulation=='n') {
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
                break;
            }
        }   

        d1.oneYear();
        d1.display();   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to parse a String to a char, whereas the String object represent more than one character, you just simply use the following expression:
*char c = (char) Integer.parseInt(s)*.
Where *s* equals the String you want to parse. Most people forget that char's represent a 16-bit number, and thus can be a part of **any** numerical expression :)

Comment: This is wrong. Parsing a string to a number means that the number was converted to a string, and we want to get the number back. Exactly the same way, parsing a character from a string means that the character was converted to a string, and we want the character back. Using an intermediate number is not what the OP asked about.

Comment: @Vlad He did ask for a number, because that's what a `char` is, just like `int` and `double`. He even gave the example `String` "123". and who says you can't convert a `char` to a `String` with a length larger than one, and back? Try it yourself with `char c = 123` : `String.valueOf((int) c).equals("123")` returns `true`.

Comment: Sorry, but everything boils down to the numbers, that's not the point of the question. You can have a look at the accepted answer, which clearly excludes an intermediate `int`. For your example, you needed to **cast** to `int`, which means that you are working not with the original `char`, but with an `int`, which happens to somehow correspond to the original `char`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.io.*;
class ss1 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        String a = new String("sample");
        System.out.println("Result: ");
        for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(a.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explenation to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
String str = "abcd";
char arr[] = new char[len]; // len is the length of the array
arr = str.toCharArray();
```

Comment: You can shorten this to a oneliner `String str = "abc"; char[] char_str = str.toCharArray();`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `toCharArray()` to convert a string to char array:

```
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter some String:");
    String str=s.nextLine();
    char a[]=str.toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.charAt(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) function with Strings to retrieve the char value at any index. If you want to convert the String to a char array, try calling [.toCharArray()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()) on the String. If the string is 1 character long, just take that character by calling .charAt(0) (or .First() in C#).

Answer (score 0):

**An Essay way :**

```
public class CharToInt{  
public static void main(String[] poo){  
String ss="toyota";
for(int i=0;i<ss.length();i++)
  {
     char c = ss.charAt(i); 
    // int a=c;  
     System.out.println(c); } } 
}
```

For Output see this link: [Click here](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/DCSLLaHtHO)

Thanks :-)