# Build char from string

Tags: java, char

I want to allow a user specify a Unicode range via an XML config file. E.g. they could state 0100..017F as the range. For my (Java) app to consume this char range, I need to convert the XML input (String) to type char. Any ideas?#

E.g.

```
String input = "0100..017F"; // I can change format of input, if enables a solution
char from = '\u0100';
char to = '\u017f';
```

Thanks.

Comment: So you mean from *string to char*, right?

Comment: input.charAt(0); doesnt help you? not should i get the question, give us a more fixed example of an input and expected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it always matches exactly that format, then this will suffice:

```
char from = (char)Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0, 4), 16);
char to = (char)Integer.parseInt(input.substring(6), 16);
```

For something more flexible:

```
char from;
char to;
java.util.regex.Matcher m = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(
    "^([\\da-fA-F]{1,4})(?:\\s*\\.\\.\\s*([\\da-fA-F]{1,4}))?$").matcher(input);
if (!m.find()) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
from = (char)Integer.parseInt(m.group(1), 16);
if (m.group(2) != null) {
    to = (char)Integer.parseInt(m.group(2), 16);
} else {
    to = from;
}
```

That allows for 1 to 4 hex digits for each character, the `..` may have space around it, and the `to` part of the range may be omitted and assumed to be equal to `from`.

Comment: Looks good thanks. In addition to your sub-strings, I will need more string manipulation code, as a (Unicode) input could be 4 or 5 chars in length.

Comment: @Damo It won't fit in a `char` then, since `char` is limited to `\uFFFF`.. you would have to make it an `int`...

Comment: Just testing out above, and not sure if its correct approach. Just to go over rqmts, I want to convert a string (that represents a char) to said char. Whereas (char)Integer.parseInt("0100") will resolve to the char 'd' - i want it to resolve to '\u0100'.

Comment: @Damo Integer.parseInt("0100", **16**);

Comment: +! for fancy flexible regular expressions.