# Error: cannot find symbol -- EC=Character.parseChar(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter employee code"));

Tags: symbols

My professor said that we need to input a letter to the dialog box in order for regular, probation etc. to show. I don't know how to resolve this problem. Is there something wrong? I'm new to java.

Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class EmployeeCode_input
{
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        char EC;
        EC=Character.parseChar(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter employee code"));
        if ((EC=="R")&&(EC=="r"))
            System.out.println("Regular");
        else if((EC=="P")&&(EC=="p"))
            System.out.println("Probationing");
        else if((EC=="T")&&(EC=="t"))
            System.out.println("Trainee");
        else if ((EC=="C")&&(EC=="c"))
            System.out.println("Contractual");
        else
            System.out.println("INVALID");
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @AndrewSchuster I'm asking if character is right in this line: EC=Character.parseChar(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter employee code"));

Answer (score 2):

`Character.parseChar` is not available in Java.

Answer (score 0):

As chinmay ghag pointed out there is no Character.parseChar in Java. You may use String's charAt() method instead.

Change :

`EC=Character.parseChar(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter employee code"));`

To :

`EC=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter employee code").charAt(0);`

See this for more information: [How to convert/parse from String to char in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853502/how-to-convert-parse-from-string-to-char-in-java)

Also if EC is of type char then you shouldn't be comparing char's with strings. ie: EC = 'p' **not** EC = "p"