# How can I turn "'\n'" (String) into '\n' (char) in java

Tags: java, string, char

Its a simple question, I have a String like this:

```
String s = "'\n'";
```

I want to turn that into a character like this:

```
char c = '\n';
```

What can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert/parse from String to char in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853502/how-to-convert-parse-from-string-to-char-in-java)

Comment: Is there always a string with one char ("\n" or "a") in it wrapped by two single quotes?

Comment: If the string is _always_ like that, why not just use `char c = '\n';` instead of picking a single char out of a string? I can't really see any use case for this..

Answer (score 3):

There are three characters, first is `'`, second is `\n` and third is `'`. You can get the second one using `.charAt(1)` since it is zero based indexing:

```
String s = "'\n'";
char ch = s.charAt(1);
```

Comment: Or `char ch = (char) (1 << 3 | 1 << 1);`, what's the point? ;) I guess there are even more confusing ways of assigning a newline to a char