# How to convert char to String in tokenizer in Java

Tags: java, string, char, stringtokenizer

Trying to read a file separated by commas into an array and not sure how to make party into a string to work with tokenizer

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
         String str = scan.nextLine();
         StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, ",");
        //String [] tokens = str.split(",");
         String name = st.nextToken();
         String abbreviation = st.nextToken();
         long population = Long.parseLong(st.nextToken());
         String govName = st.nextToken();
         char party = st.nextToken();
         int ageWhenElected = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());

         s[i] = new State(name, abbreviation, population, govName ,party, ageWhenElected);
```

Comment: I would suggest you to just stick to `.split` as it is easier to use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert/parse from String to char in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853502/how-to-convert-parse-from-string-to-char-in-java)

Comment: One thing to be careful of is your delimiter.  A comma seperated file often contains white space too, so your might want to use something like `new StringTokenizer( str, "\\s*,\\s*" )`.  Same goes for `split()` if you switch to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
char party = st.nextToken().charAt(0);
```

Comment: if my answer is helpful you can show your thanks by upvoting. If my answer resolves your issue please accept it

Answer (score 0):

You can join your array of string with comma as separator

```
StringUtils.join(strArray, ",");
```

Comment: I think the OP has the opposite problem that you are solving here