# The opposite method of Integer.toString(char)

Tags: java

```
public static String char2Str(char c) {
    return Integer.toString(c);
}
```

**EDIT:**
For example, `char2Str('ɮ')` returns `622`.

How do I implement the opposite method of the above (`str2Char()`)?

Comment: You want to reduce a string to a single char? That's not really how it works.

Comment: What are you expecting to pass into `char2Str` ? because you are taking in a `char` and treating it like an integer.

Comment: You should probably use `Character.toString(c)` rather than `Integer`

Comment: A `String` contains more information than a `char`. A `char` consists of a **single** character. A `String` may contain **multiple** character. Do you want to extract only the first character? Or rather get a whole array of characters, a `char[]`? Note that your question was asked already, simply search for "*java convert string to char*", first hit on Google. Note that a `char` is not the same as an `int`. Instead of converting using utility methods for `int` from `Integer` you should use utilities for `char` from `Character`.

Comment: At least provide some examples to demonstrate input and desired output. Otherwise your question may be **unclear**. Which it is at the moment, it is not clear if you want a `char[]` or only extract the first `char`.

Answer (score 2):

You should have something like that:

**Char to String**

```
public static String char2Str(char c) {
    return Character.toString(c);
}
```

**String to Char**

When converting String to char, your output will be an array of characters as bellow:

```
public static char[] str2Char(String s) {
    return s.toCharArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know String is of single length (just a single char), Use

```
char c = s.charAt(0);
```

Your method

```
public static char str2Char(String s) {
    return s.charAt(0);
}
```

Comment: His above sample appears to be putting the integer value in a string, this may be a case for `Integer.parseInt()`

Answer (score 0):

you have to be sure that your string contains only 1 char, then use

```
s.charAt(0)
```

if not, you can get the array of chars and then return the one you need or the whole array

```
char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can find the answer right here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7853536/9623806

If your string contains exactly one character the simplest way to convert it to a character is probably to call the charAt method:

char c = s.charAt(0);

Comment: Instead of linking like that you can just flag as duplicate... that needs 15 reputation. Before that consider answering other questions instead. (however, this answer is sufficiently self-contained, no problem)

Comment: Another suggestion: You can [format code blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: thanks for the information