# Evaluating binary tree with recursion

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

I have a binary tree containing integers in the external nodes and operators in the internal nodes. 
 I send the root node of the tree to my evaluateTree method. 
I want to traverse the tree and to calculate the final result. 
The node class's fields are

```
private Node left;
private Node right;
char value;
```

For example, I want to evaluate (2+5)/8-(21+3) should equal, with rounding, to -23. 
When I try to do so, I get a result of -5. Unrelated to rounding, when I try to calculate 21+3, i get a result of 5. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
int evaluateTree(Node node)
{
   System.out.println("Inside evaluateTree");
   if (Character.isDigit(node.value))
   {
      return Character.getNumericValue(node.value);
   }
   else
   {
      int operand1 = evaluateTree(node.left);
      int operand2 = evaluateTree(node.right);
      switch (node.value)
      {
         case '+':
            return (int) Math.round(operand1 + operand2);
         case '-':
            return (int) Math.round(operand1 - operand2);
         case '*':
            return (int) Math.round(operand1 * operand2);
         case '/':
            return (int) Math.round(operand1 / operand2);
         default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + node.value);
       }
   }
}
```

This is how i create my tree

```
public void createTree()
{
   Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
   ArrayList<String> postFixArray = new ArrayList<>();
   postFixArray = getPostFixString("(21+3)");
   System.out.println("\nCREATE TREE PRINTING\n");
   System.out.println(postFixArray);
   Stack<Node> nodeStack = new Stack<>();
   while (!postFixArray.isEmpty())
   {
      String temp = postFixArray.get(0);
      char charTemp = temp.charAt(0);
      if (!isOperator(charTemp))
      {
         if (!Character.isDigit(charTemp))
         {
            System.out.println("Enter the integer value for your variable " + charTemp + ": ");
            int setVarValue = keyboardInput.nextInt();
            for (int i = 0; i < postFixArray.size(); i++)
            {
                if (charTemp == postFixArray.get(i).charAt(0))
                {
                     postFixArray.set(i, String.valueOf(setVarValue));
                }
            }
         }
         String tempLink = postFixArray.remove(0);
         char nodeData = tempLink.charAt(0);
         Node leaf = new Node(nodeData);
         nodeStack.push(leaf);
      }
      else
      {
         if (nodeStack.size() >= 1)
         {
            String tempLink = postFixArray.remove(0);
            char nodeData = tempLink.charAt(0);
            Node leaf = new Node(nodeData);
            leaf.right = nodeStack.pop();
            leaf.left = nodeStack.pop();
            nodeStack.push(leaf);
         }
      }
   }
   Node root = nodeStack.pop();
   System.out.println(root);
   System.out.println(evaluateTree(root));
}
```

Comment: For which example it is not working . I have tried with 2+5 and it works fine.

Comment: Yeah, like @PrernaGupta said it works fine either you aren't printing the return value or your tree structure is incorrect.

Comment: Yea honestly i forgot to print the return value. But I did change the question somewhat after realizing that mistake.

Comment: Example that you have mentioned above, ((2+5)/7-(21+3)) is it working in above code. Since in your Node you are taking value as char , but 21 is not a char value and it will give error.

Comment: @PrernaGupta What would be a way to go about it ?

Comment: Can I know how you are evaluating this (2+5)/7-(21+3) to -22.6 because as per inorder traversal of the same it doers not evaluate to this.

Comment: You are going to have to create a round function for it (if I am not mistaken) will always round up. For the switch returns.

Comment: You should use double values if you want to round.

Comment: @PrernaGupta Why isnt 21 a character ?

Comment: Char takes exactly one byte . If there is more than 1 byte you need to store the same in char array . For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853502/how-to-convert-parse-from-string-to-char-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Rounding

To round the values just add a round function to the returns of the switch statements. The division you should cast it to a `double` or a `float` since it will be rounded up if you don't.

```
switch (node.value)
{
    case '+':
        return round(operand1 + operand2);
    case '-':
        return round(operand1 - operand2);
    case '*':
        return round(operand1 * operand2);
    case '/':
        return round((float) operand1 / operand2);
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + node.value);
}
```

-

```
public static int round(double x) {
    return (int) Math.round(x);
}
```

For the validating if there is an integer with more than one digit you should probably use Regex, but this problem should have its own dedicated question.

**EDIT:**
I created some test cases without a *tree creation method* to test out if *this* chuck of code was working correctly. It passed the following tests:

```
    // 21/3 = 7
public static void testCaseOne() {
    Node three = new Node(null, null, '3');
    Node nine = new Node(null, null, '9');
    Node nine2 = new Node(null, null, '9');
    Node three2 = new Node(null, null, '3');
    Node plus3 = new Node(nine, three, '+');
    Node plus2 = new Node(nine2, plus3, '+');
    Node plus = new Node(plus2, three2, '/');
    System.out.println("PASSED: " + (evaluateTree(plus) == 7) + " " + evaluateTree(plus));
}

// 21+3 = 24
public static void testCaseTwo() {
    Node three = new Node(null, null, '3');
    Node nine = new Node(null, null, '9');
    Node nine2 = new Node(null, null, '9');
    Node three2 = new Node(null, null, '3');
    Node plus3 = new Node(nine, three, '+');
    Node plus2 = new Node(nine2, plus3, '+');
    Node plus = new Node(plus2, three2, '+');
    System.out.println("PASSED: " + (evaluateTree(plus) == 24) + " " + evaluateTree(plus));
}

// 9/9/3/3 = 1
public static void testCaseThree() {
    Node three = new Node(null, null, '3');
    Node nine = new Node(null, null, '9');
    Node nine2 = new Node(null, null, '9');
    Node three2 = new Node(null, null, '3');
    Node plus3 = new Node(nine, three, '/');
    Node plus2 = new Node(nine2, plus3, '/');
    Node plus = new Node(plus2, three2, '/');
    System.out.println("PASSED: " + (evaluateTree(plus) == 1) + " " + evaluateTree(plus));
}

// 21/2 = 10.5 = 11
public static void testCaseFour() {
    Node three = new Node(null, null, '3');
    Node nine = new Node(null, null, '9');
    Node nine2 = new Node(null, null, '9');
    Node two = new Node(null, null, '2');
    Node plus3 = new Node(nine, three, '+');
    Node plus2 = new Node(nine2, plus3, '+');
    Node plus = new Node(plus2, two, '/');
    System.out.println("PASSED: " + (evaluateTree(plus) == 11) + " " + evaluateTree(plus));
}

// 22/3 = 7.33 = 7
public static void testCaseFive() {
    Node four = new Node(null, null, '4');
    Node nine = new Node(null, null, '9');
    Node nine2 = new Node(null, null, '9');
    Node three2 = new Node(null, null, '3');
    Node plus3 = new Node(nine, four, '+');
    Node plus2 = new Node(nine2, plus3, '+');
    Node plus = new Node(plus2, three2, '/');
    System.out.println("PASSED: " + (evaluateTree(plus) == 7) + " " + evaluateTree(plus));
}
```

> Validating

To further add on the validating input you could do something like:

```
String regexExpression = "([()\\-+/0-9]+)?\\d{2}([()\\-+/0-9]+)?";
String str = "(2+5)/8-(21+3)";
boolean containsLongInts = str.matches(regexExpression);
System.out.println(str + " contains long ints: " + containsLongInts);

String str2 = "(2+5)/8-(2+3)";
boolean containsLongInts2 = str2.matches(regexExpression);
System.out.println(str2 + " contains long ints: " + containsLongInts2);
```

Answer (score 1):

For rounding the value returned,  you can change return type of `evaluateTree` to `Double`and then use Math.round to round of the value, which will return an int value.

Here is the update code of function `evaluateTree` :

```
public static Double   evaluateTree(Node node)
{
   System.out.println("Inside evaluateTree");
   if (Character.isDigit(node.value))
   {
      return (double)Character.getNumericValue(node.value);
   }
   else
   {
      double operand1 = evaluateTree(node.left);
      double operand2 = evaluateTree(node.right);
      switch (node.value)
      {
         case '+':
            return operand1 + operand2;
         case '-':
            return operand1 - operand2;
         case '*':
            return operand1 * operand2;
         case '/':
            return operand1 / operand2;
         default:
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + node.value);
       }
   }
}
```

At the end wherever you are calling this method you can return its value as

`Math.round(evaluateTree(root))`

Comment: Thank you. However, unrelated to rounding, when I try to calculate 21+3, i get a result of 5.

Comment: Can you share the code of how you are creating nodes for the above expression because I am not sure how you are adding 21 to your Node value field as it is char.

Comment: I am assuming in whatever way you are adding value to your value field in Node , it is taking just first char. Exampe result of this (2+5)/8-(21+3) as mentioned by you is -5, since from 21 it is taking just 2 . So, it transfers to (2+5)/8-(2+3) => 7/8 - 5 =>0 -5 =-5 . Same is happening with 21+3 => 2+3 =5 . This is just my assumption . We can verify the same once you paste code to show how you are creating nodes of such expression

Comment: Just saw you code . For creating leaf node you are calcualating value of leaf node by doing String tempLink = postFixArray.remove(0);
char nodeData = tempLink.charAt(0);. Now suppose  postFixArray.charAt(0) value is  24 and then you are doing "24".charAt(0) which gives result as 2 and your leaf node gets created with value as 2 not 24. So, same thing that I have mentioned in my above comment is happening you are creating nodes of digit by extracting first char value of string , and not using whole string because of which it works fine for 0-9 , but after that only first character is used..